# Babel : SyntaxError: test.jsx: Unexpected token (3:11)

Tags: javascript, babeljs, reactjs

I need to transform jsx to js.So I used babel to do that,But it gives an Error as shown below.Someone please help me to resolve this.

test.jsx:

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="John" />, mountNode);
```

On command `babel test.jsx` :

> SyntaxError: test.jsx: Unexpected token (3:11)

```
  1 | var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  2 |   render: function() {
> 3 |     return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    |            ^
  4 |   }
  5 | });
  6 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the [React preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) installed to convert JSX to createElement calls.

From the website:

Installation

`npm install babel-preset-react`

Usage

Add the following line to your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

Comment: where can I find `.babelrc` for a particular project , Since I installed `bebel-present-react` locally for this project only.

Comment: in the root folder of the project

Comment: if it's not there, just create it.